# Android toolbar PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, frame, toolbar

I followed different example to insert the Toolbar in my PreferenceActivity. I eventually found a conclusion, but the FrameLayout overlaps the Toolbar, as you see in the image.
This is the XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyDarkToolbarStyle"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your layout says so.
The `RelativeLayout` needs to be told that the toolbar is on top of the framelayout or alternatively the framelayout told to be below the toolbar.

So either add this to the framelayout:

```
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
```

Or this to the toolbar:

```
android:layout_above="@id/content_frame"
```